# Java - i am making a server which sends client latest updates

Tags: java

So i have this class, this class has the string i want in my other file(String Message)
Which picks up the message from the server. I am not sure how to get the string into another package and class. any help would be amazing

```
public class Client 
{
private static Socket socket;

public static void main(String args[])
{
    try
    {
        String host = "localhost";
        int port = 43594;
        InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName(host);
        socket = new Socket(address, port);

       //Send the message to the server
        OutputStream os = socket.getOutputStream();
        OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(os);
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(osw);

        //String number = "2";
        String number = ClientSettings.ClientSettings.ClientVersion;

        String sendMessage = number + "\n";
        bw.write(sendMessage);
        bw.flush();
        System.out.println(""+sendMessage);

        //Get the return message from the server
        InputStream is = socket.getInputStream();
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
        String message = br.readLine(); //this is the string i need to get...
        System.out.println("" +message);
    }
    catch (Exception exception) 
    {
        exception.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally
    {
        //Closing the socket
        try
        {
            socket.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Define in the class that need to use the "message" a private String (with getter/setter methods)

```
public class UseMessage{

    private String message;
    private static UseMessage instance;

    private UseMessage(){
    }

    public static UseMessage getInstance(){
        if(instance==null){
            instance = new UseMessage();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    public String getMessage(){
        return message;
    }
    public String setMessage(String message){
        this.message = message;
    }
}
```

Then in class Client:

```
UseMessage.getInstance().setMessage(br.readLine());
```

If you need in another class:

```
String message = UseMessage.getInstance().getMessage();
```

Thake a look [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern)

Comment: Server sided seemed to work but the client part um.setMessage(br.readLine()); did not any ideas?

Comment: where would i put the UseMessage um = new UseMessage();
um.setMessage(br.readLine()); in client.class?

Comment: sure shall i put it in a new question? because this has only 500 chars